# difference between two different while loops with and without termination?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Whats difference in the working of

```
while(i++<100)
```

and

```
while(i++<100);
```

Is this correct that in 1st case, `i` increases until its value reach to `99` but in 2nd case,`;` is an error that's why nothing is going to happen?

Comment: what is error? can you check it again is for first case or second one?

Comment: Unless the while is the end of a do-while loop, don't write a semicolon at the end of it. If you want an empty loop, write `while(i++ < 100)` new line `;`. Or alternatively `while(i++ < 100)` new line `{}`. To show the reader of your code that the semicolon is intentional and not just some slip of the finger.

Comment: i put these statements in program then they show output like this:          1st case:   int i=1; while(i++<100) printf("%d",i); its output is 2-100 which is understandable. 2nd case: int i=1; while(i++<100); printf("%d",i); its output is 101 which is confusing me????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> *in 2nd case,";" is an error*

**NO**. Just think of this `while()` as a part of `do...while` loop. It's **perfectly valid**.

However, even in normal `while()` loop scenario, both the statements are **valid**, but their behavior is different.

1. `while (i++ < 100)`

it causes the next instruction or block following `while()` to be executed untill the condition goes to FALSE (`i` goes to `99`).

2. `while(i++<100);`

essentially does nothing, execpt increasing the value of `i` till `99`.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me the reason behind the downvote so that I can corrct myself? Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No:

`while(i++<100);` is a loop with a empty command (does nothing until `i` is 100), (there is no compilation error).

And `while(i++<100) {commands}` is a same loop but does someting.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is not terminated by a `;` - it will execute the the follows it until `i` reaches the limit.

The second one is terminated by a `;` - which means that there's an implicit empty block there. In other words, it's equivalent to having `while(i++<100) {}`. I.e. - do nothing until `i` reaches the limit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax error, just second while loop keep on incrementing till it meats the condition,

```
while(i++<100);
```

Remember `;` is statement terminator. Scope of `while` works with either on statement terminator, or scope delimiters `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

1. while (i++ < 100) - Will execute block after this statement till condition is valid i.e. i < 100.
2. while (i++ < 100); -  Will execute it self till i < 100.